# Statistical demand forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, exponential-smoothing, multiple-seasonalities

How is batch demand forecasting done in retail like in Walmart where number of products to forecast are very large in number and products are short lived i.e have less than 36 months of historical data?

I know there statistical methods like ARIMA, exponential smoothing, but in retail (for example Walmart) there are 100,000+ products ranging  in various categories like detergents, grocery etc each having its own seasonality, geographical hierarchy, product hierarchy. Also some of them have very irregular demand i.e zero in most of the months and very high in some months for example spare parts.

Comment: Forecast pro, autobox and sas forecast server all have the ability to do batch forecast for 100,000+ products, hierarchy etc. I would suspect the retailers are using one of these software. Consult their documentation for further details.

Comment: Yes but what methods they use for very small time series where number of data points are not sufficient to capture seasonality.

Comment: Naive methods and analogues time series are used for short time series or no historical data. For irregular data, you could use intermittent demand forecast method

Comment: Why would "spare parts" have "very irregular demand"?